# React App working on localhost but not working on Netlify deploy because the API call is different

Tags: reactjs, axios, netlify

I am developing a React app using freetogame API and it works perfectly on localhost, but I deployed it on Netlify and it's not working because it's making the API call to a different adress.
Here is the API call on localhost: [localhost API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgu8s.jpg)

and here is the API call on the deployed site: [Deployed Site API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPbMC.png)

As you can see in the deployed site API call, the Request URL is completely different and there is an /undefined/ part in the API call. I don't know what's causing this problem.
Here is the Github link to the project: [Project Github Link](https://github.com/mucahitduz/Games-App)

Please help me find the solution. Thanks in advance

Edit: I did some more research and figured that the problem may be caused by the axios call. There is baseURL, headers, and params in my axios call and I didn't defined them in the Netlify deploy. Here is my axios call: [Axios Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q5PQ.png) and here is my package.json file: [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biY3V.png)
. How can I define them in netlify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added your environment variables to Netlify?

```
api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY  
api_host = process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST
api_base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
```

If you don't declare the above variables in your Netlify project it won't know what values to insert, which is why they are currently undefined. Visit this link for more information: [Netlify Environment Variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/)

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and wanted to post it here so it can help others. I tried deploying my build file to Netlify manuelly and the site is working now.